# Postgis syntax PARALLEL error

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I can't create extension in my db.  throws a error that says

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR: syntax error at or near "PARALLEL"
  Position: 2445
```

Is there any solution for this issue ?

```
PostgreSQL version 9.6.
PostGis version 2.3.
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I'm using MacOS. @EvanCarroll

Comment: You should ask these questions on dba.se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one could possibly debug this without knowing a lot more information, but it's either

- a (syntax) error in the extension itself
- you're not running PostgreSQL 9.6 (maybe you have some earlier version installed alongside it)

Connect to the database that you ran `CREATE EXTENSION` on, and run this

```
SELECT version();
```

My assumption is that you're **not** on a 9.6 server, and that you're connecting to some earlier version of PostgreSQL. [PARALLEL was new with 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/parallel-query.html).

Comment: Yes. It's really server version is 9.5.

Comment: How i can upgrade server to 9.6 ?

Comment: No idea. That's a different question. check their dl page. Mark this answer as chosen if you're satisfied with it. https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/